# Find Two elements in the Array that add up to the Target number in O(n * log n) Time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a problem with **O(n * log(n))** searching algorithm.

I have to find two numbers from an array that add up to the given number.

I know how **O(n * log(n))** works, but I'm not sure if those two correct numbers will meet in search if I do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j = j*2)
```

Is there a way to keep **O(n * log(n))** complexity so that every two numbers meet in the search?

Comment: What you have there is O(n^2), not O(n*log(n)).

Comment: So you need to two elements of the array that adds up to the target number? Any pair of number will do? Are there any other restrictions in your assignment apart from the time complexity **O(n*log(n))**?

Comment: Any pair, no restrictions, the only condition is to keep O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. sort array (O(nlogn))
2. for each element:

   2.1 binary search to find other element that adds up to the given number (or to figure out there is none)   (O(logn))

Step 2 has complexity O(nlogn), and so the whole algorithm has O(nlogn)

Comment: if array is sorted, binary search is not required

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I fail to see how else we would ensure O(nlogn) complexity for the second part.

Comment: the idea is if `k < l` then `a[k]+a[l+1] >= a[k]+a[l] >= a[k-1]+a[l]` and in order to find two indexes we need traverse array from left and right simultaneously and either increment left index if interim sum less than target sum or decrement right if interim sum greater than target sum - that has O(n) time complexity

Comment: After sorting, a single linear search is enough.

Comment: okay, to sum everything, if I sort the array with merge sort and get the nlogn complexity then i should just do linear search and my programs complexity will stay nlogn right?